# How to override a virtual method with a different return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
class Distribution
{
    public:
       virtual type GenerateRandomNumber() = 0;
};
```

Within the Distribution class, there is a function that the derived classes must override it.
One of the derived classes returns `double` and another one returns `unsigned int`.

```
class Gamma : public Distribution
{
   public:
      double GenerateRandomNumber() override;
};


class Poisson : public Distribution
{
   public:
      unsigned int GenerateRandomNumber() override;
};
```

I try `auto` as the return type of the `GenerateRandomNumber()` in Base class but it is not possible to use auto and virtual simultaneously.
What should the return type be in Base class?

Comment: have temple as return type then

Comment: Can't do that. The function signatures have to match. If you template them, the base class needs to be templated and you're usually no better off because the base types don't match. If your compiler's up to date you can return a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). Personally I think you could be marching into a bad place. See the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have conflicing return types. If you make your base class a into a class template, you'll get what you need, but the derived classes will not share a common base class.

Example:

```
template<typename type>
class Distribution {
public:
    virtual type GenerateRandomNumber() = 0;
};

class Gamma : public Distribution<double> {
public:
    double GenerateRandomNumber() override;
};


class Poisson : public Distribution<unsigned> {
public:
    unsigned int GenerateRandomNumber() override;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have identify what best fit for your solutions base on the following clarification,

1. Are you going to use Base pointer to access derived methods?.
2. The implementation of Gamma returns double precision or a integral type.
3. Are you concerned about any data loss from gamma. (I thinking about why gamma is made a double precision).

If you wanted to use base pointer and cannot afford a data loss from gamma, you should go with a double precision as double to long int will lead to a data loss.
Also as a recommendation don't use different return types for a virtual function as it may leads to misbehavior of your application.

I hope it helps!.